# Loop over iterator with changing size and values

Tags: arrays, julia

This is best explained by example. I would like to do something like:

```
tstops = [20;40]
for i in eachindex(tstops)
  if tstops[i] == 20
    push!(tstops,70)
  end
  if tstops[i] == 40
    push!(tstops,60)
  end
  if tstops[i] == 70
     tstops[end] = 100
  end
  @show tstops[i]
end
```

but actually have it show 20, 40, 60, 70, 100 (in that order). The problem with this setup is that `eachindex(tstops)` is a `Base.OneTo{2}` and so it only prints 20 and then 40, without dynamically changing. If I instead use the iterator directly:

```
tstops = [20;40]
for t in tstops
  if t == 20
    push!(tstops,70)
  end
  if t == 40
    push!(tstops,60)
  end
  if t == 70
     tstops[end] = 100
  end
  @show tstops
  @show t
end
```

This outputs:

```
tstops = [20,40,70]
t = 20
tstops = [20,40,70,60]
t = 40
tstops = [20,40,70,100]
t = 70
tstops = [20,40,70,100]
t = 100
```

So I would need a fast way to keep this sorted for this to work. However, even if it goes in sorted, the mutation at the end doesn't make it hit both 70 and 100, just 70:

```
tstops = [20;40]
for t in tstops
  if t == 20
    push!(tstops,60)
  end
  if t == 40
    push!(tstops,70)
  end
  if t == 70
     tstops[end] = 100
  end
  @show tstops
  @show t
end
```

Note that the implementation should try to get as good performance as possible too. Is there a good data structure to handle this, both the sorting and the "mutating the current point"?

---

#### Edit

Let me try to summarize it in one line: I want to be able to loop through `t` in `tstops` and hit every value of `tstops` in order, but (the hard part) I want to be able to dynamically change `tstops`.

Comment: Just use a while loop instead, where you check the iteration variable i against the current length?

Comment: Oh, I think I missed the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact behavior desired is not clear to me, but perhaps this will do:

```
using Base.Collections
tstops = [20,40]
heapify!(tstops)
while !isempty(tstops)
  t = heappop!(tstops)
  if t == 20
    heappush!(tstops,70)
  end
  if t == 40
    heappush!(tstops,60)
  end
  if t == 70
    heappush!(tstops,100)
  end
  @show tstops
  @show t
end
```

Which results in:

```
tstops = [40,70]
t = 20
tstops = [60,70]
t = 40
tstops = [70]
t = 60
tstops = [100]
t = 70
tstops = Int64[]
t = 100
```

Comment: Maybe post your solution once you have it done, which might clarify the original question as well?